# GraphQL and graphql-sequelize-schema-generator

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql, express-graphql

I've build one small code using graphql, nodejs, express and sequelize (with mysql) but I'm can't find the magic of graphql yet. I'd create my models using sequelize-cli (using sequelize model:create etc.) and I'd generating dynamically my schemas and types like that:

```
var types = generateModelTypes([db['User'], db['Acesso']])
var schema = generateSchema({User: db['User'], Acesso: db['Acesso']}, types)
```

And I'd opened my app on the follow way:

```
app.use(
    '/graphql',
    graphqlHTTP({
        schema: schema,
        graphiql: true
    })
)

app.listen(4000, function (){
    console.log("Calling app.listen's callback function.");
})
```

But I can't send one query on graphiql using that:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{ "query": "{ users { id } }" }' localhost:4000/graphql
```

I get this error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Expected [object Object] to be a GraphQL schema."}]}
```

What I doing wrong!?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for `graphql-sequelize-schema-generator`, the generated schema isn't actually an instance of GraphQLSchema, so you need to do something like this:

```
schema: new GraphQLSchema(schema)
```